# How to solve $\csc \left(\sqrt{x}\right)+\sec \left(\sqrt{x}\right)=2 \sqrt{2}$ symbolically?

Tags: equation-solving

Here is my try.

```
Solve[Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] == 2*Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
>       4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]^2 - 8 [Pi] ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] C[1] + 
>        4 [Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] [Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}, {x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[
>       4 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2 + 
>        8 [Pi] ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]] C[1] + 
>        4 [Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] [Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1]}, {x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[
>       4 ArcTan[2 + Sqrt[6] + Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2 + 
>        8 [Pi] ArcTan[2 + Sqrt[6] + Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]] C[1] + 
>        4 [Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] [Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}}

The same result is produced by `ToRadicals@Reduce`. However, the verification

```
N[Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] - 2*Sqrt[2]] /. 
 x -> 4 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2 + 
8 \[Pi] ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]] C[1] + 4 \[Pi]^2 C[1] /. 
  C[1] -> 1]
```

> 10.0745

does not confirm it.

Note. Maple correctly performs $\frac {{\pi}^{2}} {16},{\frac {121\,{\pi}^{2}}{144}} $ for the first two roots.

Addition. My verification is not correct as @xzczd noticed. The Mathematica's answer is right. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this equation

```
gl = Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] == 2*Sqrt[2]
```

directly with Mathematica

```
sol = Solve[{gl, 20 > x > 0}, x, Reals, Method -> "Reduce"]
(*{{x -> 4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]^2}, 
{x -> 4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]^2}, 
{x ->4 ArcTan[Root[1 + 8 #1 + 2 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 4]]^2}}*)
```

which gives the first 3 roots

To get all roots in analytical form you can substitute `Sqrt[x]->2 ArcTan[u]`
(in german called "Halbwinkelsubstitution")

```
glu = FullSimplify@TrigExpand[Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] - 2*Sqrt[2] /.Sqrt[x] -> 2 ArcTan[u] ];

solu=Solve[glu == 0, u]

(*{{u -> -1 + Sqrt[2]}, 
{u -> -1 + Sqrt[2]}, 
{u ->2 + Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[9 + 6 Sqrt[2]]}, 
{u -> 2 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[9 + 6 Sqrt[2]]}}*)
```

Solving the substitution  `u=Tan[Sqrt[x]/2]` for x and inserting solu gives you the roots in analytical form!

Comment: Thank you. How to obtain all the real solutions? How to obtain the solutions in explicit form similar to Maple's one?

Comment: Just look at the range I gave in the Solve-command. With a simple substitution you can evaluate all solutions (I edit my answer)

Comment: Sorry, what is your g1?

Comment: It's your equation `gl = Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] == 2*Sqrt[2]`

Comment: Sorry, the set of the solutions of the equation under cosideration is infinite, but your solu consists of four items. BTW, did you verify your results? Thank you anyway.

Comment: I didn't consider the periodicity of the problem, I suppose it can be  easily  included.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eq = Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] == 2*Sqrt[2] /. Sqrt[x] -> y

(*  Csc[y] + Sec[y] == 2 Sqrt[2]  *)
```

Then:

```
Reduce[eq && y > 0, y]

(*  C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && ((C[1] >= 1 && 
     y == 2 ArcTan[Root[1 + 8 #1 + 2 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]] + 
       2 \[Pi] C[1]) || (C[1] >= 
      0 && (y == -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1] || 
       y == 2 ArcTan[Root[1 + 8 #1 + 2 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 4]] + 
         2 \[Pi] C[1])))  *)
```

These are the solutions. Let us take, say, the first of them and make it looking better:

```
2 ArcTan[Root[1 + 8 #1 + 2 #1^2 - 8 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]] // ToRadicals

(*  2 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]  *)
```

Let us now check, if this, indeed, is a solution:

```
(eq /. y -> 
    2 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]) // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

Done.

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, but the equation under consideration is in x, not  y. Please, answer the original question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user64494 Please calculate the square of the given solution.

Comment: The verification Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] - 2*Sqrt[2] /. x -> N[(2 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]])^2] performs 2.07055, not 0. –

Comment: @user64494 It seems that you are right. Indeed, this `(Csc[y] + Sec[y] /. 
   y -> 2 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]) // FullSimplify` verifies correctly to `2 Sqrt[2]`. On the other hand, this `(Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] /.x ->  (2ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]])^2) // FullSimplify` verifies incorrectly to `2 Sqrt[6]`. I think, this points out to a bag, and one needs to address the bug suspicion to the Support. On the other hand, if you ask which one of the two solutions is correct, it is the first one. The one that proofs right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Solve[Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] == 2*Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
```

Under version 11.2 the result is correct:

```
    {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
    4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]^2 - 8 \[Pi] ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] C[1] + 
     4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    4 ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2 + 
     8 \[Pi] ArcTan[2 - Sqrt[6] - Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]] C[1] + 
     4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[
    4 ArcTan[2 + Sqrt[6] + Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2 + 
     8 \[Pi] ArcTan[2 + Sqrt[6] + Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]] C[1] + 
     4 \[Pi]^2 C[1]^2, C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}}
```

In fact , N[%]:

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[0.61685 + 9.8696 C[1] + 39.4784 C[1]^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0.]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[1.71347 - 16.4493 C[1] + 39.4784 C[1]^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1.]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[8.29321 + 36.1885 C[1] + 39.4784 C[1]^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0.]}}
```

Compare the first roots i.e. C[1]=0 to

```
N[Pi^2/16]
```

0.61685

and

```
N[Pi^2*121/144]
```

8.29321 . As you can see the results are correct.

```
FullSimplify[4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]^2]

\[Pi]^2/16
```

and

```
FullSimplify[4 ArcTan[2 + Sqrt[6] + Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]^2]


(121 \[Pi]^2)/144
```

The complete simplified results are:

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/16 (\[Pi] + 8 \[Pi] C[1])^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[4 \[Pi]^2 (-(5/24) + C[1])^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[4 \[Pi]^2 (11/24 + C[1])^2, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 0]}}
```

If you still don't trust the results, use the plot

```
Plot[Sec[Sqrt[x]] + Csc[Sqrt[x]] - 2*Sqrt[2], {x, 0, 16}]
```

Comment: Sorry, version 11.3  performs the identical result with the one claimed by you and this result is not correct.

Comment: Read the answer first.